# Proper form for printing a newline (python)

Tags: python

If I just want to print a newline in python, is it better form to use `print('')`, or `print('\n', end = '')`, or something else?

`print('\n', end = '')` seems over complicated, while `print('')` feels a bit strange.

Comment: Nothing wrong with print as far as I can see.  You could also add a '\n' in your previous print statement.

Comment: Python 2 or 3? You're mixing their syntaxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *Python3*, if you simply need to print a newline character, then you use:

`print()`

Looking at the documentation for `print()`, it shows that the default `end` character is `'\n'`.

```
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```